# GUI "dot on icon" indicators for hard disk, network ... activity?

Tags: indicator, gui

If you have seen VirtualBox, you may have noticed its set of indicators for hard disk, CD-rom, network, USB etc:

[image: vbox-indicators]

The cool thing about this (for me) is that the indicators are "animated", in the sense that an "activity dot" appears whenever there is activity on the particular device, in (near) real-time (above, there is a red dot for activity on the hard disk icon, and green dot for activity on the CD-ROM icon - not sure if green means read, and red means write).

Is there something like that for Ubuntu, that works on the Ubuntu OS level? I use MATE as my desktop environment by the way... This doesn't have to be an applet related to top bars - could be OSD (on-screen display) like `conky`; however, I just need blinking dots on icons, not textual info or usage history graphs (as usually used in `conky` or Gnome applets).